# TensorFlowlite Object detection demo app activity(Android studio) won't launch

Tags: java, android, tensorflow-lite, object-detection-api

Trying to tweak the app by launching the DetectorActivity(main activity that does the detection) only when a button is clicked.
 So within the source code, I've added a class "Main Activity", set it as the launching activity in the manifest, and in it's xml, added a button that when clicked, should send an intent to the DetectorActivity and launch it. The code is pretty much this :

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void on(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,DetectorActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

However, the activity is never launched, which is quite baffling.
Here is the logcat of the emulator:

```
 I/art: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
12-21 20:39:13.111 23543-23550/.abc I/art: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
12-21 20:39:13.563 23543-23543/.abc W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
12-21 20:39:13.745 23543-23554/abc I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 9521(535KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 75% free, 950KB/3MB, paused 8.576ms total 187.364ms
12-21 20:39:14.110 23543-23543/abc I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
12-21 20:39:14.112 23543-23543/.abc I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
12-21 20:39:15.082 23543-23577/abc D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
12-21 20:39:15.338 23543-23577/.abc I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-21 20:39:15.338 23543-23577/abc W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
12-21 20:39:15.387 23543-23577/abc D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x7f758dd74f40: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
12-21 20:39:15.403 23543-23577/abc D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f758dd74f40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f758dd532a0)
12-21 20:39:15.777 23543-23577/abc D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f758dd74f40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f758dd532a0)
12-21 20:39:16.102 23543-23543/abc I/Choreographer: Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-21 20:57:47.896 23543-23550/abc I/art: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
12-21 20:57:47.909 23543-23550/abc I/art: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
12-21 21:00:48.853 23543-23550/abc I/art: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
```

Any help in this matter would be truly appreciated!

Comment: How are you setting the click listener?  This log suggests it's not being called.

Answer (score 0):

> How are you setting the click listener? This log suggests it's not being called.

The comment by @RyanMentley solved it, thanks a bunch.